# Simulating a spring/damper system in Yampa

Tags: haskell, physics, frp, yampa

I'm trying to use Yampa for some basic system simulation like I'd do in Simulink. In this case I want to simulate a spring and damper system, introduced by [this simulink tutorial](http://prism2.mem.drexel.edu/~rares/MassSpringDamper.htm). I've written the following signal functions to represent the system:

```hs
system = time >>> force >>> displacement

force = constant (m * g)

displacement = feedback (-) (velocity >>> integral) (gain $ k / m) 0
velocity     = feedback (-) integral                (gain $ c / m) 0
```

Where the `feedback` function creates a [basic feedback loop](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/ed/Ideal_feedback_model.svg) and is implemented like this:

```hs
feedback op a b b0 = loopPre b0 inner
    where inner = arr (uncurry op) >>> a >>> (identity &&& b)
```

Oh, and:

```hs
gain x = arr (*x)
```

With sensible positive constants, I get a wildly unstable system:

[image: plot of displacement/time]

Is there something obviously wrong in the way I'm constructing feedback loops or applying the integration?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change `integral` to `imIntegral 0`

```
displacement = feedback (-) (velocity >>> imIntegral 0) (gain $ k / m) 0
velocity     = feedback (-) (imIntegral 0)            (gain $ c / m) 0
```

From spring.hs:

[image: Yampa]

Using Simulink:

[image: Simulink]

Something funny is happening in the integral function, changing to `imIntegral 0` gives the same curve as in matlab.

My guess is that `Integral` is delayed by one sample, since it doesn't have a starting value, changing the behaviour of  the loop.

Comment: Excellent, thanks heaps for that! I had done some simple tests with `integral` so I didn't think that was an issue. By 'the scale is off', do you mean the horizontal axis? My code doesn't plot time, just the # of each data point.

Comment: darn, nevermind about that, when I was comparing matlab and simulink I had something off that made the diference in the y scale.

Comment: Adding a transport delay in simulink makes the system unstable similarly to the one you've found, so that's must be it.

Comment: Oh, of course. Try simulating a system that's just `time >>> integral >>> integral`. The first couple of samples are 0 while the integrators warm up. I had no idea that small delay would be enough to destroy the system stability.

Comment: It is! Since you are adding a transport delay in the feedback loop, you add a lot of phase in your system, which is similar to throwing the poles around.

edit: yeah, just simulated that code, it shows a 2 samples delay, one for each integrator.